# how to dynamically change the position of buttons

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button

I have a `MainActivity` initially empty with an action bar. Clicking on the "plus" in the action bar,I open a `DialogFragment` with an `EditText` and two buttons, "cancel" and "continue". I can not post a picture because I do not have enough reputation, but when I click on "continue" I create two buttons; one positioned at the top right of the layout of `MainActivity` and the other, just below the previous one, on the left. What I would like is that every time I click on "continue", I can create two buttons positioned according to the same pattern that I explained earlier.

This is the code I've written but it does not work as I would like.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements IProjectDialFrag {

    private ProjectDialogFragment projectDialFrag = new ProjectDialogFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                //TODO
                return true;
            case R.id.filters:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FiltersActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_new:
                return true;
            case R.id.add_button:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ButtonsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                return true;
            case R.id.add_project:
                projectDialFrag.show(getFragmentManager(), "projectDialog");
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) { 
        EditText editText = (EditText) dialog.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.project_name);
        String projectName = editText.getText().toString();

        Button projectButton = new Button(this);
            projectButton.setText(projectName);

        ImageButton playButton = new ImageButton(this);
            playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play_over_video);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.button_row);
            linearLayout.addView(projectButton);
            linearLayout.addView(playButton);
    }

}
```

The Interface

```
public interface IProjectDialFrag {

    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);

}
```

And the DialogFragment

```
public class ProjectDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private IProjectDialFrag iProjDialFrag;

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         AlertDialog.Builder createProjectAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

         createProjectAlert.setTitle("Create Project");

         LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

         createProjectAlert.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.project_dialog_fragment, null))

            .setPositiveButton(R.string.conti_nue, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    iProjDialFrag.onDialogPositiveClick(ProjectDialogFragment.this);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    iProjDialFrag.onDialogNegativeClick(ProjectDialogFragment.this);

                }
            });

         return createProjectAlert.create();

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        iProjDialFrag = (IProjectDialFrag) activity;
    }

}
```

The layout of MainActivity

```
<RelativeLayout 

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" > 

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" >
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

If you need a screenshot, please give me a point reputation and I'll place it immediately. Than you

Thank you again. Here is my screenshot:

[image]

This is the result I'd like to have:

[image]

For each Button I have to be able to add more "play".

Comment: screenshot please... and what exactly do you want? that only two buttons add when "continue" is clicked or should they keep growing?

Comment: Define row layout xml with horizontal LinearLayout and two child button now when continues button click just add this row layout xml to button_row Linearlayout.

Comment: @udiboy1209 I'd like to place "play" button on the left just below the previous button with the string. You understand correctly, my idea is that they should keep growing. I have to be able to add many "play" buttons one below the other. I place two images that show the resulta I'd like.

Comment: @Haresh Can you explain better?

Comment: @Riccardo can you please guide how can i place the multtiple dynamic buttons with random position in a relative layouts

Answer (score 0):

But see your layout.

Your linear layout is "wrap_conent" on the width.
Also your linear layout is glued to the right side of parent.
So that is exactly what you will be getting... all the linear layout content glued to the right side and taking exaclty size of it's content... Well Button. You are getting what you told Android to get.

If you want to get what you drawn, then 1st your linear layout for button shoul be match_parent in widht, and you can set it's gravity to left for play buttons and to right for CIAO and LUCA buttons...

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    ... >
```

in MainActivity layout should change to

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    ... >
```

and add these lines

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) <---
lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT; <---

Button projectButton = new Button(this);
    projectButton.setText(projectName);
    projectButton.setLayoutParams(lp); <---

lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT; <---
ImageButton playButton = new ImageButton(this);
    playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play_over_video);
    playButton.setLayoutParams(lp); <---
```

Comment: It does not work. With the code you suggested, buttons are placed both on the right side of the layout. I just changed some piece of your code and it finally works! Thank You!

Comment: @Riccardo what change did you make?

Answer (score 0):

@udiboy1209

I simply refactor your code as I show below:

```
  @Override
  public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) { 
    EditText editText = (EditText) dialog.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.project_name);
    String projectName = editText.getText().toString();

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp1.gravity = Gravity.END;

    Button projectButton = new Button(this);
        projectButton.setText(projectName);
        projectButton.setLayoutParams(lp1);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp2.gravity = Gravity.START;

    Button playButton = new Button(this);
        playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_button_green);
        playButton.setLayoutParams(lp2);

    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.button_row);
        linearLayout.addView(projectButton);
        linearLayout.addView(playButton);

}
```